# Ionic 4: Make Form Update Itself with Every Input

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make an Ionic unit conversion app. On my last try, I got the conversion working, but it was reflected 1 edit too late (e.g. I'd type “124”, and it would show the conversion for “12” until I change the value again, which would show the conversion for “124” regardless of what the new value became.)

Neither my tutor nor I could figure out what was causing this delay. I used simple [(ngModel)] binding, but it doesn't work as intended. How do I achieve this effect?

I don't have code snippets because I exasperatedly started over, but I had a function that fired on change, which *should* update one of the two text inputs immediately.

EDIT: I've recoded this from scratch, and encountered the same problem, so here you go:

convert.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>{{category.category}}</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div class="ion-padding">
    <form>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input id="usValue" type="numeric" [(ngModel)]="usValue" name="usValue" (ionInput)="convert()"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-select id="usUnit" [(ngModel)]="usUnit" name="usUnit" (ionInput)="convert()">
          <ion-select-option *ngFor="let us of category.usUnits; index as i" value="{{i}}">
            {{us.namePlural}}
          </ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input id="siValue" type="numeric" [(ngModel)]="siValue" name="siValue"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-select id="siUnit" [(ngModel)]="siUnit" name="siUnit">
          <ion-select-option *ngFor="let si of category.siUnits; index as i" value="{{i}}">
            {{si.namePlural}}
          </ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </form>
    {{usValue}}, {{usUnit}}, {{siValue}}, {{siUnit}}
  </div>
  <script>

  </script>
</ion-content>
```

convert.page.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Unit, Category } from '../../../assets/unitclass';
import { UNITDATA } from '../../../assets/unitdata';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-convert',
  templateUrl: './convert.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./convert.page.scss'],
})
export class ConvertPage implements OnInit {
  index: number;
  category: Category;
  usValue = 1;
  usUnit = 0;
  siValue = 1; // will be initialized
  siUnit = 0;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.index = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('category'));
    this.category = UNITDATA[this.index];
  }

  convert(){
    this.siValue = this.usValue * this.category.usUnits[this.usUnit].value / this.category.siUnits[this.siUnit].value;
  }
  convertBack(){
    this.usValue = this.siValue / this.category.usUnits[this.usUnit].value * this.category.siUnits[this.siUnit].value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with code to replicate the problem?

Comment: @TomasVancoillie I do not have code snippets because I started over.

Comment: @haley It's impossible to tell what went wrong without seeing the faulty code.

Comment: Really? Not even a clue on which one of the many conflicting approaches found online I should take?

Comment: @TomasVancoillie Added recoded snippets.

Comment: @AnjilDhamala Added recoded snippets.